# X1 Carbon Mini Display works with External Monitor but not Projectors

Tags: lenovo, vga, displayport, projector

I have an X1 Carbon 2014 model, and everything seems to work great on Ubuntu 14.04. Recently now I've had to use it twice to give a presentation, and both times it's failed to detect the VGA projector. I've used it at home with both a VGA and a DVI monitor and it works fine. I'm using the Apple VGA and DVI mini displayport adapters, which I've used for years on an old Dell with MiniDP and now with the X1 Carbon.

When it comes to projectors though, the laptop refuses to even acknowledge that the projector is there. I can plug it straight into a monitor with the same adapter and it works fine.

I'm kind of at a loss as to what to do.

Comment: In the end I just put Windows 7 back on the machine for a dual boot. If I need to use a projector I'll just reboot. The problem seems completely on the Linux side since both monitors and projectors work fine in Windows 7, but only monitors work in Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: I have the same problem with Dell XPS 2013 with Ubuntu 14.10. Monitor are ok. Projector are not. My test is with lots of monitors and a Panasonic projector with Mini DisplayPort to VGA adapter.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I also tried it with a Mac adapter, which I luckily borrowed from a friend, which did work for displays but not projectors. Due to this fact, I then bought a Lenovo adapter, which works fine. All under Linux, don't have a Windows installation any more.